# Is the Series Sin(k)/k Absolutely Convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, absolute-convergence

I know that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin k}{k}$ converges (to $\frac{\pi - 1}{2}$), though by crazy stuff with Dirichlet Kernels or by reverse-engineering $\frac{\pi - x}{2} = \sum \frac{\sin (kx)}{k}$ using Fourier Series.

My question instead: Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin k}{k}$ **absolutely convergent**?

My gut instinct is no: It behaves not-much-better than $\sum \frac1k$, but that's certainly not a rigorous proof.

Comment: The $k$s such that $\sin k > 1/2$ are evenly enough distributed that your gut instinct can be made rigorous.

Comment: No, by Kronecker's lemma. The absolute value of sin(k) has a positive mean value, equal to 2 over pi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to investigate whether $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin k|}{k}$ convergent.

Note $\forall k\in\mathbb{N},[\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi,\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi]$,$\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi-(\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi)=\frac{4\pi}{6}>1$, hence there exists $n_k\in\mathbb{N},n_k\in[\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi,\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi]$. Hence $|\sin n_k|>\frac{1}{2}$, and $\frac{1}{n_k}\geq \frac{1}{\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi}>\frac{1}{(1+2k)\pi}$.

$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$, we find such $n_k$, then $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin k|}{k}>\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin n_k|}{n_k}>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+2k)2\pi}$$

the RHS series is divergent, by comparison test with hamonic series. So the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Aha, that's very sleek and definitely rigorous! Thanks!

(Minor note on the last line: Should be RHS divergent by comparison.)

Comment: @D.J. You are right. Sorry for the typo. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @john Can u please tell how to prove this.$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin k|}{k}>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac {|sinn_k|}{n_k} $