# If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ is large, then does $\sum_{n\in A} \frac{\vert \sin n \vert }{n}$ diverge also?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, irrationality-measure

> If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ is large, that is, $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in A}
>  \frac{1}{n}$ diverges,  then does $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in A}
>  \frac{\vert \sin n \vert }{n}$ diverge also?

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\vert \sin n \vert }{n}$ diverges. For example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005902/is-the-series-sink-k-absolutely-convergent). So this deals with the case $A=\mathbb{N}.$

I guess my question has to do with the [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) of $\pi$ also.

Or is there some standard convergence test which can help here?

Comment: What does "large" mean?

Comment: @LeeMosher It is standard terminology which I also explained what it means in the blockquote part of the question.

Comment: If $A$ is the set of primes, the series $$\sum_{p}
 \frac{\vert \sin p \vert }{p}$$ diverges as we can show by using the prime number theorem with a good remainder, so even for sparser large sets we get divergence (also clearly the series diverges if the set has positive density); on the other hand it may be possible to use the uniform distribution of $n/\pi$ modulo $1$ to construct large but sparse sets (zero density like the primes) where the series is not that large, though it may still diverge

Comment: @Conrad ok but we can try for better $A$ than the set of primes. I don't see why that would be a good attempt at a counter-example to my question.

Comment: Ah, got it. Your "that is" language was a bit abbreviated and threw me off.